# Android 9 back button when launching settings activity works incorrectly

Tags: android, android-activity, android-9.0-pie

In our application we have a special buttons which takes the user to network settings page. We use the following code

```
 Intent intent=new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS);
 startActivity(intent);
```

There are several issues with this implementation in Android 9.

1. for some reason I see a back button when Network & Internet settings is launched. Pressing that back button takes user to the "Settings" page, instead of taking them back to my application. This is not desirable at all.
2. Even worse, pressing the System back button takes user completely back to launcher, thus totally breaking the navigation back stack.

[image]

In Android 8 however everything works just fine, neither there is a software back button at the top, nor the system back buttons has the behavior described above.

[image]

What is wrong with Android 9? Is there a special activity action flags that I should put into the intent that launches the network settings?

P.S.

Both of the phones are Nokia 2.1, one with Android 8.1, one with Android 9.0.

Comment: Have you find the solution yet?

Comment: @JaswantSingh not really, that's the way android works as it's described in the below answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Android 9 implementation is the correct one, and that's why they changed it:

https://developer.android.com/training/design-navigation/ancestral-temporal

> The Up button appears in the app bar and is used to navigate within an app based on the hierarchical relationships between screens.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But that implementation doesn't make any sense. Cause if I have launched the settings from my application, if user wants to go back to my app there's no way, both "up" and "back" buttons will take them to different places.

Comment: I would agree them doing different things, but different right things. I don't think the behavior I see is correct, cause it doesn't make sense going from App1 to Settings, then press back and go to launcher instead of going to App1, don't you agree?

Comment: I ran the code on my Pixel 3 running Android 9. Pressing the Back button returns me to my app, not to the launcher.

Comment: Thanks that's valuable information. I guess that might be an issue of my phone.

Answer (score 0):

I think Correct flow should be:-
1. On Navigation Up -> Any app will navigate within an app.
2. On System back button App will move to previous Activity in Task or to Previous task (If launched with `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`).

During testing on Android 9.0 Device i found this same behavior. In your case This MayBe a build issue. The device i have tested on have the below config.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When you say "During testing on Android 9.0 Device i found this same behavior. " what do you mean by same behavior?

Comment: The same i have mentioned in my answer . Sorry for confusion . The device is a Stock android Motorola One Power. So you can go with it cause it looks like a build/device dependent flaw.

Comment: So, just to be clear, when you press system back button it does go to the application from where the Settings screen was launched right? You are not taken to system launcher don't you?

Comment: I found the same issue in the Android 9 Samsung S9+ device after July 1, 2019. But the behaviour is as expected on June 1, 2019 and before. Do you have any workaround?