# Android 9 inconsistent behavior with Settings actions with back button/back arrow

Tags: android, android-intent, settings

I'm developing a shortcut settings app that opens some settings (Wifi, Location and Bluetooth). I wish
that when the user go back it's to my application and not the settings app.

To launch the correct setting page I do:

```
val intent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_BLUETOOTH_SETTINGS)
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
startActivity(intent)
```

On `android 8` there is no issue because the top back arrow is not present and the back button returns to my app.

On `android 9` for `Setting.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS` and `Settings.ACTION_BLUETOOTH_SETTINGS` the top back arrow opens the settings main page but the back button goes back to my app.

For `Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS` both top arrow and back button returns to my app. Which is the behavior I want.

On `android 10` both top arrow and back button returns to my app. Which is the behavior I want.

I don't know how to "fix" the inconsistent behavior for `Setting.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS` and `Settings.ACTION_BLUETOOTH_SETTINGS` on android 9.

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60164057/settings-action-sound-settings-is-not-going-back-to-app?rq=1) but without success. And also stumbled upon this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55076066/android-9-back-button-when-launching-settings-activity-works-incorrectly?rq=1) that states that it is the standard behavior but it doesn't seems to be the case since some options behave differently.

EDIT:

Seems to be a manufacturer issue:

- The described is seen on an Archos Oxygen 101S
- On a Samsung X Cover it always goes back to the settings and not my app